# How to loop through each item and return the corresponding value for each instance (jquery and scrollmagic)

Tags: jquery, loops, each, scrollmagic

I’m using scroll magic (awesome) to trigger events when a div (.overNav) enters a trigger zone. I have multiple .overNav divs, so I’m using an .each() loop to fire for each instance. That works, but I also need to find the height of each div and tell scroll magic to update a *unique* duration for each *unique* instance. This halfway works...

**The script below returns the height for each .overNav div, BUT it returns ALL overNav div heights for each instance. *I’m not sure how to specify the first .overNav div to use the first overNav div height, and the second to use the second, and so on.*** The console.log I’m using spits out *both* heights for *each* instance. The script is updating the duration with only the *last* overNav height, not the correct one.

So I’m inside an each loop, and expected each function within that loop would return info for that specific instance. What am I doing wrong? I’m fairly untrained and basically bushwhack my way through these things. This one has me stumped.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {   
//Init ScrollMagic
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller(); 
//Scene 3 Loop - send .underNav objects under the sidenav
    $('.overNav').each(function() {
        // build a scene
        var overNavScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
            triggerHook: '.25',
            reverse: true,
            triggerElement: this
        })
        .setClassToggle("#sidenav", "fade-out")
        //get height of each overnav on enter
        .on("enter", function() {
            $('.overNav').each(function() {
                var overNavHeight = $(this).height()   
                overNavScene.duration(overNavHeight);
                console.log(overNavHeight);
             });
        }) 
        .addTo(controller);
    });   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this is useful to anyone else, I think I figured it out. I needed to pass "this" further into the nested function, so I declared it in a variable and removed the additional each loop downstream.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {   
//Init ScrollMagic
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller(); 
//Scene 3 Loop - send .underNav objects under the sidenav
    var $thisss = this; // THIS was the key
    $('.overNav').each(function() {
        // build a scene
        var overNavScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
            triggerHook: '.25',
            reverse: true,
            triggerElement: $thisss
        })
        .setClassToggle("#sidenav", "fade-out")
        //get height of each overnav on enter
        .on("enter", function() {
            $('.overNav').each(function() {
                var overNavHeight = $($thisss).height()   
                overNavScene.duration(overNavHeight);
                console.log(overNavHeight);
             });
        }) 
        .addTo(controller);
    });   
});
```